# Well-ordering and proper subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to show:

$\forall m, n \in \omega (n < m \iff n \subset m)$

I have shown the forward direction, but I'm confused for the reverse.

I have stated $n \subset m \iff \forall z(z \in n \rightarrow z \in m) \text{ and } m \ne n$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\omega$ is well-ordered. In particular exactly one of the three must hold:

1. $n\in m$,
2. $n=m$,
3. $m\in n$.

Show that if $m\subseteq n$, then either $n=m$ or $m\in n$. Conclude that if $n\subsetneq m$, then $n\in m$.

Comment: do you mean show $n \subset m$? I don't see how else it is useful?

Comment: Think contrapositive.